# Copy one row to multiple rows on another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a sheet with multiple project numbers: [Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9cVI.png)

[image]

I have another sheet with the same project numbers but with more information: [Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPSbG.png)

[image]

What I need to be able to do is quickly copy the information on sheet two to sheet one filling in the correct information to the correct project number

I will have hundreds of rows to fill out, so I would like to find an efficient way to populate the rows.

Comment: You need to give more info. What you've tried, example data, if you want it formatting differently, if you want it copying as is etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=VLOOKUP(A1, G:Z, COUNTIF(A$1:A1, A1)+1, FALSE)&TEXT(,)
```

Fill down.

[image]

Comment: Woah - that's a clever solution.  What does the `&text(,)` at the end do? I see what you did with the `Countif()` part, which is a neat 'trick', but can't guess really what that end formula does.

Comment: `...&text(,)` is the same as `...&""`. When attempting to return a text value with a VLOOKUP but encountering a blank cell to return, VLOOKUP will return `0` (i.e. *zero*). By appending a zero-length string to the return value you end up with a zero-length string as the return; not a `0&""`. Additionally, appending a zero-length string to text does not change the text so valid returns are not affected. I don't recommend using this method to return numbers since appending a zero-length string to a number will cause that true number to become text-that-looks-like-a-number.

Comment: so is that a shortcut to using `=If(vlookup()=0,"",vlookup())`? So if I'm trying to return some string (not number) and I want to leave a cell blank if nothing is found, it's quicker than wrapping in that `If()` statement?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. Sort of a crude IFBLANK. Remember that a zero-length string is not truly blank; it just looks that way.

Comment: @BruceWayne - Additionally, if the vlookup does not return zero, you are recalculating the same vlookup a second with the IF statement; using the zero-length string as a suffix, it is only ever calculated once.

Comment: Oooh good point.  Thanks for all your comments! I always learn something new when you show up :D

Answer (score 0):

you can use VLOOKUP funtion to fill with the data

ex.
put in Sheet1 B1 as follow

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$D$5,2,FALSE)
```

then in C1

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$D$5,3,FALSE)
```

and D1

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$D$5,4,FALSE)
```

change to your range and fill down